# R script to open folders then identify a file, rename it, and read it

Tags: r, rename

I have recently learned to code with R and I sort of manage to handle the data within files but I can't get it to manipulate the files themselves. Here is my problem:

I'd like to open successively, in my working directory `"Laurent/R"`,  the 3 folders that are within it (`"gene_1"`, `"gene_2"`, `"gene_3"`).

In each folder, I want one specific .csv file (the one containing the specific word "Cq") to be renamed as "gene_x_Cq" (and then to move these 3 renamed files in a new folder (is that necessary?)).

I want then to be able to successively open these 3 .csv files (with read.csv i suppose) to manipulate the data within them.
I've looked at different functions like `list.file`, `unlist`, `file.rename` but i'm sure they are appropriate and I can't figure out how to use them in my case.
Can anyone help ? (I use a Mac)
Thanks
Laurent

Comment: Hi Laurent! Are there any other files in your "gene_1", "gene_2" etc folders that have the word "Cq" in them? This will help folks tailor an answer to you.

Comment: Check out `file.choose`, `file.rename` and `list.files`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential solution. If you don't understand something, just shout out and ask!

```
setwd("Your own file path/Laurent")
library(stringr)

# list all .csv files
csvfiles <- list.files(recursive = T, pattern = "\\.csv")
csvfiles

# Pick out files that have cq in them, ensuring that you ignore uppercase/lowercase
cq.files <- csvfiles[str_detect(csvfiles, fixed("cq", ignore_case = T))]

# Get gene number for both files - using "2" here because gene folder is at the second level in the file path
gene.nb <- str_sub(word(cq.files, 2, 2, sep = "/"), 6, 6)
gene.nb

# create a new folder to place new files into
dir.create("R/genefiles")

# This will copy files, not move them. To move them, use file.rename - but be careful, I'd try file.copy first.
cq.files <- file.copy(cq.files,
                        paste0("R/genefiles/gene_", gene.nb, "_", "Cq", ".csv"))

# Now to work with all files in the new folder
library(purrr)
genefiles <- list.files("R/genefiles", full.names = T)

# This will bring in all data into one dataframe. If you want them brought in as separate dataframes,
# use something like gene1 <- read.csv("R/genefiles/gene_1_Cq.csv")
files <- map_dfr(genefiles, read.csv)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nova, it did help me !!

Comment: That's great Laurent! If you like my answer, you can "upvote" it (see arrows beside my answer, top left). You can also "accept" my answer (check mark below voting area) so that other users know that your question is answered if they search for something similar. Voting and accepting answers helps users like me increase reputation points, and these points can later be used to offer "bounties" for our own questions.